# How to get the Joined Rooms History in aSmack API?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack, asmack

I am working on the chat module of the project. I need to integrate the Group chat functionality. I did n't find in the API to get the joined rooms history programmatically using the aSmack API.

Suppose I join the room then I save in the mobile database, once user uninstall the application then it destroy this database from the mobile then next time when same user install the application then user is not able to get the Joined rooms from the aSmack API

Please help me is there any way to get the Joined rooms history.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If u okay with flat file, Check whether it helps..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19683614/android-persist-data-after-uninstall

Comment: @Vigneshearan.m alright but i am looking a way how this can be possible using asmack library

Comment: are you using openfire server for chat

Comment: i post my answer, i hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

save your users group detail on server and create a webservice to get grouplist of user.
i do same thing for this, from this way you can able to get grouplist from another device.

and if you wants group chat history then this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25947985/how-to-get-offline-message-of-group-chat-from-openfire) is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

XMPP has no such concept as "Joined MUC History".

But there are Bookmarks defined in [XEP-0048](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0048.html), that are commonly used to store "often visited MUCs". You may want to have a look at this.

Comment: Thanks to suggest me. Can you help me How can i achieve this using asmack api in android

Comment: I want to get the Joined MUC History of particular users. Please help me how can i using the aSmack API

Comment: please help if there is any way to do this programmatically