# How can i store a file in device that after uninstall app the file does not delete? (firemonkey)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

How can i store a file in a way that after uninstalling the application, the given file **does not delete**, by the way, i have the **premission** to create the file in that path and that path not viewed for user to delete the file manually? (delphi-xe5)

Comment: This is most likely related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6109152/1970843. It states that the only way to have persistent data is to use sdcard.

Comment: This one is probably even more related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19683978/1970843